# Map over a promise from fetch and render to the page with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using fetch to return a promise which is working however Im not able to map over this data. My console log returns undefined.

```
const dataPromise = fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=GB');

let newArray;

dataPromise
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(data => {
    //console.log(data) // This works
    newArray = data.map((item)=>{
      return item.name;
    });
  })
  .catch((err)=> {
    console.error(err);
  });

  console.log(newArray); // This doenst work
```

I need to create a variable with the mapped data so I can render it (with React).

Comment: As your `fetch` request is asynchronous your console.log(newArray) is executed before the value is returned form the server.  This is the expected behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are fetching this data in order to populate a React component, I suggest you to execute this request on `componentDidMount` and then `setState` afterwards. Remember that `fetch` is asynchronous and therefore you won't be able to get its result back right away.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=GB')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => this.setState({ data: response }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: I think theres an error in this code. It says "Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ;" at "fetchData() {"

Comment: @Evans I've just updated my answer. Please check again :)

Answer (score 0):

I belive you need to setState. I dont know if this is best practice or not but the following works:

```
const dataPromise = fetch('http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=GB');

dataPromise
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(data => {
    //console.log(data) // This works
    const newArray = data.map((item)=>{
      return item.name;
    });
    this.setState({property: newArray});
  })
  .catch((err)=> {
    console.error(err);
  });
```